# Displaying my json result but it only returns 1 result from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi I have a working script on my javascript for my chat application but I noticed on my console that my json result returned as 1 single result only when i used `.append()` so I switched to `.text()` it also returned my json result but this time only 1 conversation was retrieved from my database.. What I want is to retrieve everything just like on `.append` but each are displayed individually 
here is what I have so far :
         $("#user-list").find("a").on("click", function(e){
            $(".wtf").fadeIn(300);
            e.preventDefault();
            var uid = $(this).data('uid');
            $('.wtf #rid').val(uid);

```
          var rid = $('#rid').val(),
              user = $('#usernas').val(),
              suid = $('#uid').val(),
              data = {chat: suid, rid: rid, name: user};
        $.ajax({
              url: "includes/uid-chats.php",
              type: "GET",
              data: data,
              dataType: 'json',

           }).done( function(result){

           $.each(result, function(rowKey, row) {
           $(".media-heading").text( row.username );
           $("p").text( row.message_content );
            });
      });

         });
```

The reason why I didn't want to continue using `.append()` is because the chat is loaded on a styled `<li>`... Any suggestion on how can I solve my problem?

```
0
    Object { msgid="2014041412", message_content="asdsaf", username="ab.cd", more...}

1
    Object { msgid="2014041412", message_content="asdfff", username="ab.cd", more...}

2
    Object { msgid="2014041412", message_content="a", username="ab.cd", more...}
```

This is what the firebug gave me under JSON tab there atleast nine result I just pasted few to cut it short

And on my main page it only displays

ab.cd

ccc

only

Comment: post your json returned..

Comment: master @Madhu I have edited my post I've included the json result as per required

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle..

[http://jsfiddle.net/madhust/Aa65D/](http://jsfiddle.net/madhust/Aa65D/2/)

In that i have created the `li` as per the json length and appended to the `ul` dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

you are iterating through the object and overwriting the text value of the same element on every iteration. try something like:

```
$.each(result, function(rowKey, row) {

       var newEl = $('<div><h2 class="media-heading"></h2><p></p></div>');
       $(newEl.find('.media-heading')[0]).text(row.username);
       $(newEl.find("p")[0]).text( row.message_content );
       $('body').append($(newEl));

});
```